# Use of the personal pronoun demonstratively

Tags: grammar-identification, personal-pronouns

I notice in the following sentence from Cicero, he seems to be using the personal pronoun demonstratively:

*De meis scriptis misi ad te Graece perfectum consulatum meum. eum librum L. Cossinio dedi.* ("Concerning my writings, I sent you my completed work on the consulship in Greek. I gave this/the book to Lucius Cossinius.")

Here, where it says *eum librum*, I would have expected *hunc librum* ("this book"). What is the explanation of the grammar here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would in fact be more accurate to say that *is, ea, id* is a **demonstrative** pronoun that is often used **personally**, rather than a personal pronoun that is used demonstratively.

[Lewis & Short](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dis) refers to it as a demonstrative pronoun, and this is also how it is introduced in [Allen & Greenough § 146](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/demonstrative-pronouns-paradigms):

> The Demonstrative Pronouns are used to point out or designate a person or thing for special attention, either with nouns as Adjectives or alone as Pronouns. They are: hīc (this); is, ille, iste (that), with the intensive ipse (self), and īdem (same)1 and are declined below.

On the particular usage of *is, ea, id*, see [Allen & Greenough § 296-97](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/demonstrative-pronouns). Here are two particularly relevant parts:

> Demonstrative pronouns are used either adjectively or substantively.
>
> 1. As adjectives, they follow the rules for the agreement of adjectives and are called Adjective Pronouns or Pronominal Adjectives. . . .
> 2. As substantives, they are equivalent to personal pronouns. This use is regular in the oblique cases, especially of is.

Note: this observation applies to *all* demonstrative pronouns, not just *is, ea, id*. "Hic" and "ille" can mean "he" just as much as "is," depending on the context. You are right, though, that *is* is more commonly used as a personal pronoun by itself.

Regarding the particular usage of *is, ea, id*:

> [§297] d. ***Is* is a weaker demonstrative than the others and is especially common as a personal pronoun.** It does not denote any special object, but refers to one just mentioned, or to be afterwards explained by a relative. Often it is merely a correlative to the relative *quī*.

This explains your Cicero quote. Here's how I would translate:

> De meis scriptis misi ad te Graece perfectum consulatum meum. eum librum L. Cossinio dedi.

> I have sent you, from my writings, my completed [book on] consulship, in Greek. I gave that book to Lucius Cossinius.

Keep in mind, though, that it's a "weak" demonstrative, so you could also translate with "this" or even "the."